# Pretty URLs and rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to get to where I can create a pretty URL for a custom post type (The end goal being to add a unique value to the query string so I can leverage page caching).  So for example the original developer has `/boats/page/1/` working fine and via `add_query_arg` I can get `/boats/page/1/?zip=05443`.  I'd like to turn that into `/boats/page/1/zip/05443/` and have tried via rewrite rules but am either missing something or the rewrite rules are not being called.  Here is the rewrite rule I added.

```
$rules = array(
    '^boats/page/(\d+)/zip/(\d+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=boat&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . 'zip=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
);
$wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge($rules, $wp_rewrite->rules);
```

This is being called as part of a hook into `generate_rewrite_rules`.

I can get the URLs to look correct but they generate a 404 when I click them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anyone?  I'm struggling here and I'm sure I'm missing something small.  I did see that the rewrite rules only get inserted into the DB if you update permalinks and if I echo out `$wp_rewrite` I do see them (on the permalinks admin page).  Any suggestions / pointers would be greatly appreciated!